# Redirect to specific https

Tags: nginx, redirect, port

I have a service that is run from port 3888. I can access it by going **http**://website.com:3888/ .I want to be able to add access it in a secure way so I did a reverse proxy on nginx to the ssl port 443.

```
server {
        location /srv/ {
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3888/;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 600s;

            proxy_redirect    off;
            proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Fair enough. Now I can access it in a secure way at `https://website.com/srv/`.

But I cannot get rid of the old link as I can still access it.

`http://website.com:3888/`

Is there any way to not show this link? Or to redirect it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this block of code beneath should resolve your problems ->

```
server {
        if($host = yourdomainname.com) {
               return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomainname.com www.yourdomainname.com
    return 404;
}
```

The return 301 basically redirects all the traffic to the HTTPS version and should prevent anynone from being able to access the HTTP version.

Comment: I have that already in place. Every request is redirected to https version. I need to link http://website.com:3888/ to https://website.com/srv/. And http://website.com:3888/ needs to be redirected.